# Navigation redirecting to domain.compagename.html instead of domain.com/pagename.html

Tags: php

Here is the problem, click a nav link at www.getboda.com and it redirects to redirecting to domain.compagename.html instead of domain.com/pagename.html

The same exact code is in place at dev.getboda.com and works just fine. Below is the menu code.

ANY IDEAS?

```
<ul id="navlist">
 <li id="homeButton"><a <?php if($pageName == 'home'){ echo 'class="active"'; } ?> href="http://<?php echo $serverName;?>/index.php"><span>Home</span></a></li>
 <li id="howitworksButton"><a <?php if($pageName == 'howitworks'){ echo 'class="active"'; } ?> href="http://<?php echo $serverName;?>/howitworks.php"><span>How It Works</span></a></li>
 <li id="researchButton"><a <?php if($pageName == 'research'){ echo 'class="active"'; } ?> href="http://<?php echo $serverName;?>/research.php"><span>Research</span></a></li>
 <li id="faqButton"><a <?php if($pageName == 'faq'){ echo 'class="active"'; } ?> href="http://<?php echo $serverName;?>/FAQ.php"><span>Frequently Asked Questions</span></a></li>
 <li id="testimonialsButton"><a <?php if($pageName == 'testimonials'){ echo 'class="active"'; } ?> href="http://<?php echo $serverName;?>/testimonials.php"><span>Testimonials</span></a></li>
</ul>
<div class="clearBoth"></div>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask

Comment: The referring pages (`index.php`, `howitworks.php`, etc.) are within the same domain, you can just use relative links for `href` omitting `$serverName` variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the http to https (as a quick fix). But the issue you are having is a server problem. Your code outputs the correct url, its that your server looks like it is setting the url as the server name. Check the redirection from http to https. Thats the source of your problem.

Comment: Thank you, this was correct. The problem was in the httpd-vhosts on the permanent redirect line.

Comment: You still have to address your link tags, what's the point of redirecting a user to a https:// url, only to have all your links point to http:// each time redirecting?

Answer (score 0):

Look towards your .htaccess or other url rewriting configuration you have, performing wget -d on the non https url shows an invalid 301 redirect:

```
301 Moved Permanently
Registered socket 376 for persistent reuse.
Location: https://www.getboda.comhowitworks.php [following]
```

Comment: These are the redirect settings in apache config: